# Specify which Route to go to on when ASP.NET Application Starts for Mobile Views with DisplayModeProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a requirement in which I need to use a key that will come from the `webconfig` file which will specify which `View` to render when the application will start. This is only a one time thing since after the application starts, the other operations work normally. I have tried to look for some `filter` methods but they work after the application starts. I am looking for a solution that will only check for this key once and render the appropriate `View`. This is specifically for Mobile Views. I have registered my `DisplayModeProvider` in `Application_Start()`.

Do I need to do this in `RouteConfig.cs` or `ApplicationStart()` method?

It would be great if someone could direct me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I achieved this functionality by doing the following:

1. Setup my logic for finding out the device the application is rendered on by using `DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("Mobile")` in the `Application_Start()` method
2. Adding a key called `IsOnePageViewEnabled` in the `web.config`
3. Bind my Landing Page to a `View` called `Index.mobile`, since `MVC` automatically looks for a `*.mobile.cshtml` when you start the application
4. When the `Index.mobile` is rendered on a mobile, I retrieved my key from the web.config: `var IsOnePageViewEnabled = @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsOnePageViewEnabled"];`
5. The last step was simply checking this key and then redirecting to the appropirate `View`:

   ```
   @if (IsOnePageViewEnabled == "0")
   {
   <script>    
           window.location.href = '@Url.Content("~")' + "Home/MindexO";
   </script>
   }
   else
   {
   <script>  
           window.location.href = '@Url.Content("~")' + "Home/Mindex";   
   </script>
   }
   ```

If there are other and better ways to achieve this functionality, I would really like to know.

Answer (score 0):

This will be achieved by specifying the Default Route in RouteConfig.cs.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{" + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultController"] + "}/{" + WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultAction"] + "}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

And in your Web.config file :

```
<add key="DefaultController" value="Default" />
<add key="DefaultAction" value="Index"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how can you achieve this on mobile views. I have `DisplayModeProvider` setup in my  `Application_Start` method. I want the ability to switch mobile view based on key from config file.